# What would torsion in spacetime look like?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, thought-experiment

Christoffel symbols explain the gravity we observe in our daily lives. Say I have a region of spacetime with high [torsion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torsion_tensor), so general relativity isn't a good description of the region. In that region, be it a room or a Solar system depending on what would make for a good thought experiment, what would be empirically different from GR's predictions? We'll focus on classical effects, viz. something like [Einstein-Cartan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein%E2%80%93Cartan_theory) or whatever else would be a "mainstream" theory with torsion.